# Does MSpec have a "global" cleanup capability?

Tags: mspec

I am using MSpec to drive my browser tests, but I keep forgetting to close the browser. Rather than put this cleanup in every context, can it be applied globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [quote](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2009/11/18/mspec-v0-3/) from the author in the only article I could find on the subject...

> You can implement a [`ICleanupAfterEveryContextInAssembly`](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/Source/Machine.Specifications/ICleanupAfterEveryContextInAssembly.cs) to perform cleanup after every context (think cleaning up static state, resetting your ServerClock/DateTime replacement for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit specifications. Cleanup defined in the base specification class is invoked after all child cleanups.